# Transfer Video to Sony Walkman NWZ-S544

Tags: video, conversion, encoding, mp4

How do I transfer an MP4 video file to my Sony Walkman NWZ-S544?  It transfers but then I cannot play it because I get a "format not supported" error.  The file I'm transferring is a standard MP4 video file made to be played on a desktop.

This question is identical to the [one here](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-229280-my-sony-nwz-s544) but I do not know how to save a video in Avidemux.

Answer (score 2):

Download [Sony's Image Converter](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-list.pl?mdl=MSSWIC2P&UpdateType=Everything&SelectOS=7), instructions for conversion here:

> http://www.kb.sony.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=C557490&fes=true

Or go to [ViDEOHelp.com](http://www.videohelp.com/) and check out HandBrake under Tools. Download and install HandBrake freeware to convert using "ipod" preset, make sure fps=29.97, MAX bitrate is 768kbps, advanced tab bottom window "level=13" (NOT level=30) for Sony Walkman. Read the comments for help with Sony.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to convert video, as always, is ffmpeg.  This works for Sony NWZ-S545 (and E453, and probably S544, etc):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b 567k -s 320x240 -vcodec mpeg4 -ab 220k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec libfaac output.mp4
```

You'll need an faac encoder for this (libfaac on ubuntu); maybe it works without `-acodec libfaac` as well.

Comment: And if you do not have the libfaac encoder, just use this slightly modified command which uses the internal aac encoder: `ffmpeg -i inputfile -b 567k -s 320x240 -c:v mpeg4 -ab 220k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4`. You can find some more possibilities using mencoder and ffmpeg [here](http://fluxcoil.net/doku.php/hardwarerelated/sony_walkman_and_linux). Btw. I didn’t want to compile ffmpeg myself, I just downloaded the static build from [here](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/).

Answer (score 0):

Download the converter. It will change your video to mpeg 4. That's what the Sony Player NWZ S544 needs.

They fail to tell you that.

However, the converter is free and quick to download. Just google "sony nwz s544 media converter" and go from there. It's painless and you can finnaly use it.